# Trouble Installing pyqt4-dev-tools

Tags: python, pyqt4, apt-get

Hello I have this problem with PyQt4-dev-tools that include:
 * a user interface compiler (pyuic4)
 * a resource file generator (pyrcc4)
 * a translation string finder (pylupdate)
The problem comes when I want to convert my code saved from Designer into a module using:

```
pyuic4 untitled.ui>test.py
```

and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pyuic4", line 3, in <module>
    import PyQt4.uic.pyuic
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/PyQt4/uic/pyuic.py", line 4, in <module>
    from PyQt4 import QtCore
RuntimeError: the sip module implements API v8.0 to v8.1 but the PyQt4.QtCore module requires API v7.1
```

I have tried upgrade,remove and re install, manually install etc...

here is the complete log of what i did: http://pastebin.com/2DYfAwdC

PD Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sip python module must have been reinstalled to a newer version which is now incompatible with your PyQt installation. I would recommend removing sip, PyQt, and Qt, and then reinstalling them.

Check that your apt is up to date, and also confirm that you don't have an old PyQt installation sitting somewhere in your pythonpath.

If you are able to successfully import PyQt by itself then try comparing the import paths to make sure you aren't pulling another version of PyQt:

```
# from a shell
python -c "from PyQt4 import QtCore; print QtCore.PYQT_VERSION_STR, QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR; print QtCore.__file__"
```

Compare the versions and the PyQt4 location to the one being dumped out from your traceback when using pyuic4

If its a matter of sip being found in a different location, try adjusting your PYTHONPATH to confirm:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6")

from PyQt4 import QtCore
```

If this works without crashing, then you should probably remove the newer sip that is causing a conflict from here: "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/sip.so"

Comment: Thanks but this is the third time I have remove them and re install them.

Comment: Is your apt up to date? There might be a mis-match in versions. It would definitely work if you build these all manually.

Comment: if you mean apt-get update... Yes. Also apt-get upgrade Also i forgot to mention that I am running Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: it does not execute here is the output: [lexel@ ~] python -c "from PyQt4 import QtCore; print QtCore.PYQT_VERSION_STR, QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR; print QtCore.__file__"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: the sip module implements API v8.0 to v8.1 but the PyQt4.QtCore module requires API v7.1

Comment: Also make sure your sip is not in more than one place: `python -c "import sip; print sip.__file__"
`

Comment: output: /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/sip.so

Comment: Thats obviously a different location than `/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/`. Seems like you have sip being found first in a different spot and its newer.

Comment: So this actually work, but how can i change /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/sip.so to /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/. I mean in sys.path there is no sip.so

Comment: sip.so will not appear in your sys.path. Only the packages directories. Either remove `/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/sip.so` from your system, or in your ~/.profile add `export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6:$PYTHONPATH`